# Set a predeclared but uninitialized vector as an alias of another

Tags: c++, vector, alias

In the following code, I want the vector `v` to be set to vector `in` without it's contents being copied but I cannot use reference like `vector<int> &v = in` because v has already been declared. What changes should I make to prevent copying?

```
class pt
{
private:
    vector<int> v;
    int size;

public:
    void construct(int n)
    {
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            v[i] = v[i - 1] + v[i - 2];
        }
    }

    pt(vector<int>& in, bool no_Copy = false)
    {
        if (no_Copy)
        {
            &v = in;    //I want to fix this
        }
        else {}

        construct(in.size());
    }
    //other functions which use `v`
};
```

Comment: The statement "set vector A to vector B without copying its contents" does not make any sense in C++. This is like saying "take the box with the shiny balls that's on your left, and put this box on your right, but without moving any shiny balls inside the box. They must remain on your left.

Comment: I think this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the problem you're actually trying to solve? What is the purpose of `pt`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I mean something similar to references like `vector<int> &v = in`

Comment: So do you want to move the contents rather than copying them?

Comment: That would be a pointer. `vector<int> *v=&in;`. You don't have to set the pointer, if you don't want to.

Comment: @Brian The constructor `pt` assigns `v` to `in` if `no_copy` is true. It's just an option provided to the user. `v` is supposed to have `k` zeros followed by the elements of `in` where k is the size of `in`. So if  `no_copy` is true, it means that `in` itself has those preceding zeros else zeros have to be added to `v` and then elements of `in` have to be copied.

Comment: @Carl Is moving faster than just adding an alias?

Comment: Maybe a vector of [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) is what you are looking for..?

Comment: @user8611116 Assuming you do not need the original vector being passed to the constructor, it will be faster than copying.

Comment: is `no_Copy` always known at compile-time? In that case you would use templates here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
vector<int> v;
```

can not be "switched" from not being to being an alias.

You could make it always an alias, which in one case refers to the passed `in` vector, and in the other case to a copy of the `in` vector.

For example:

```
class pt
{
private:
    vector<int>& v;
    vector<int> v_copy;

...

pt(vector<int>& in, bool no_Copy = false)
: v(no_Copy ? in : v_copy)
{
    if(!no_Copy) v_copy = in;
}
```

Or you could also move from `in`, as @Carl suggested in a comment. This is fast but would destroy the `in` vector.